# Getting user readable name via LDAP with PHP by having only the login credentials

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am integrating my login form with Microsoft active directory. I authenticate
users via LDAP php library.

When user try to log in, they enter username & password.
Connecting to server go successfully, authentication via "LDAP_bind" also 
give me true or false according to the values correctness.
Now i am not able to retrieve the user Real name to display it on the screen.

ALL Information I have are the ldap uri with the port number, and username & password entered via the webform.

here is my current code,

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://abc.xyz:123");
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $_REQUEST['username'].'@abc.xyz',$_REQUEST['password'])) 
{ echo "Welcome". $_REQUEST['username'];}
```

the $_REQUEST['username'] is not human readable, so i need to read this user attributes or at least display name only.

ldap_search and ldap_read functions did not help, I tried this code:

```
$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=abc,DC=xyz';
$search_filter = "(objectclass=*)";
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);
```

with no luck, is there any other information i must have in order to make the ldap_search or ldap_read work successfully. in other words can this be done by having the username and password and the ldap uri only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the search like this:

```
$upn = $_REQUEST['username'].'@abc.xyz';
$attributes = ['displayname'];
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userPrincipalName=".ldap_escape($upn, null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER)."))";
$baseDn = "DC=abc,DC=xyz";
$results = ldap_search($ldap, $baseDn, $filter, $attributes);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);

// This is what you're looking for...
var_dump($info[0]['displayname'][0]);
```

Also, make sure to do the bind with these options:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://abc.xyz:123");
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $_REQUEST['username'].'@abc.xyz',$_REQUEST['password']))
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked with me. my problem finally has been solved. thanks alot. note i change the line of filter to: $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(userPrincipalName=".$upn."))"; without espcape fun.

Answer (score 0):

When returning the `DisplayName` value, I recommend that you use a search filter which looks for the `samaccountname` (username) using something as simple as `(samaccountname=$u)` with `$u` being the username from your LDAP connect. If your Active Directory/Open Directory has a lot of objects, I would most certainly recommend targeting OU's as this query can fall on it's bottom pretty quickly.

I've made some further changes to your code so it now runs inside a function which takes 3x params and returns false if the connection or authentication fails.

**Check LDAP** - Return **DisplayName** if success login or **FALSE(BOOL)** if fail login or connection.

```
function chkLDAP($u, $pass, $domain) {

    $dom = "$domain\\"; //Domain Prefix for UNAME which ouputs "domain\"
    $user = $dom . $u; 
    $hostname = 'ldap://abc.com';
    $baseDN = 'OU=users, DC=abc, DC=com'; //Narrow down if you have alot of objects as search could take along time
    $search = "(samaccountname=$u)"; //Compare with Username

    $ldap = ldap_connect($hostname);

    if ($ldap) {

        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $pass);

        if ($ldapbind) {

            $ldapSearch = ldap_search($ldap, $baseDN, $search);
            $entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap, $ldapSearch);
            $info = ldap_get_values($ldap, $entry, "displayname"); 

            return $info[0];

        }

        return false; //Failed Auth

    } 

      return false; //Connection Failed

}
```

Just test the function for false to make sure you have a `displayname` before using it.

**Run Function:**

```
$displayName = chkLDAP($_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password'], 'abc.com'); //Run Function - Returns False if Failed or Displayname if True

if ($displayName !== false) {

    echo $displayName;

} else {

    echo "Username or Password Incorrect!";

}
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-values.php

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work with me, it give me warning.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for people who need to validate if a user exists in a specific OU.
(by the help of @kitson88 response)

```
    function validateLogin($username,$password)
{
            
    $ldap_dn = "$username@alhait.com";
    $ldap_password =$password;
    
    $ldap_con = ldap_connect("server");
    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
    {
         $baseDN = 'OU=trainers,DC=alhait,DC=com';
          $search = "(samaccountname=$username)";
        $ldapSearch = ldap_search($ldap_con, $baseDN, $search);
        $entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap_con, $ldapSearch);
        $info = ldap_get_values($ldap_con, $entry, "displayname"); 
        // var_dump($info[0]);
        if($info[0]!=null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
        //echo "Invalid Credential";
        return false;
    
}
```